# How to limit the information sent in the CSV (Google Sheets)?

Tags: google-sheets

I used the script below to create a submit order button which emails the current sheet as a CSV and then clears range I6:I. How can I update it so that only items with a response in range I6:I are included in the CSV? I don't want the CSV to include anything if I6:I is empty. I know the code isn't very clean. I'm new to this. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
function SUBMIT_ORDER() {


SpreadSheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
SheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
var recipients = "EMAILADDRESS"; 
var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var subject = "BMVS " +actualSheetName+ " New Purchase Order " +dateTime ;
var body = email+ " submitted a new purchase order for " +actualSheetName+ " on " +date+ " at " +time+ " ****THANK YOU****";
var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + SpreadSheetId + "/export?format=csv&gid=" + SheetId;
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData);
var contents = result.getContent();
RESET_QUANTITIES = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()




MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body, {attachments:[{fileName:actualSheetName+'-'+dateTime+ ".csv", content:contents, mimeType:"application//csv"}]});






RESET_QUANTITIES.getRange("i6:i").clearContent();

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('E1'));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

### solution by script

Try

```
var contents = result.getContentText().split('\n').filter(r => (r.split(',')[8] != '')).join('\n')
```

instead of `var contents = result.getContent();`

### solution by query

apply in a new tab

```
=query('Feuille 1'!A:J,"select * where I is not null",1)
```